As a US Citizen, can I sue a US company for not paying me my whole salary as a contractor from Mexico?
I’m a US Citizen living in Mexico, working as a “contractor” for a US company. They do an international wire transfer to Mexico to pay my salary. I realized they havent been paying the whole amount of what was accorded. Can I sue if they dont plan on paying me what they owe?

Have you talked to them before thinking of suing them? Maybe there was an error on their part, or they deducted part for tax reasons or similar.

Have you checked that this is not just mandatory tax withholding? Have you filled and returned the appropriate W8 form? Alternatively it could be wire transfer fees from your bank (though this should remain a relatively small amount).

If they fail to live up to the terms of your contract with them, you can sue them for breach of contract.  Your citizenship and place of residence do not change this.
Whether it makes sense to sue them is of course a different question; the answer depends on many factors, and the fact that you live in a different country will probably affect that analysis significantly.  Your lawyer ought to be able to explain the various options, their cost, and the likelihood of success.
